# How to modify from and to values in grafana

Tags: grafana, html-encode

I am having troubles understanding how the following works

`from=now-1h&to=1568789063000`

but when I do

`from=1568789063000-1h&to=1568789063000` it doesn't work.

I have tried doing it directly in the URL, doesn't work.

`from=1568789063000-1h&to=1568789063000` and `from=1568789063000-2h&to=1568789063000` shows me the same time range on the graph whereas

`from=now-1h&to=1568789063000` and `from=now-2h&to=1568789063000` shows me different time range in the graph.

Additionally, I also tried manipulating this by using the option `Data link` in the visualization  where I tried using

`from=${__value_time}-1h&to=${__value_time}` and I don't plan to use `__url_time_range` becasue I want custom time range around one point.

Can please anyone explain what I am doing wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The Unix timestamps you're using (1568789063000) all translate to the same time. So doing `from=1568789063000&to=1568789063000` doesn't return a valid period of time  as

*1568789063000 - 1568789063000 = 0*

`now-1h` and `now-2h` will show different time ranges because you're telling Grafana to start the graph either at one or two hours before the time that you're making the render request, even if the `to` time is always the same

As for the issue using the absolute timestamp with a relative "offset" (`1568789063000-1h`), this isn't allowed. Instead you should subtract 3600000 from the *starting* (`from`) timestamp which equals `1568785463000`. So, if you do `from=1568785463000&to=1568789063000`, it should work instead of `from=1568789063000-1h&to=1568789063000`.

Similarly for `-2h`, you should subtract 7200000: `from=1568781863000&to=1568789063000`.

Comment: So taking your recommendation I tried this ```from=1568843640000-3600000&to=1568843640000```, this doesn't work but if I give absolute value  ```from=1568840040&to=1568843640000``` does work. And what I want is to give a relative value, is there a way to do it? Right now I am trying to do this using the ```Data link``` where I am doing this: ```from=${__value_time}-3600000&to=${__value_time}```

Comment: is there a reason one works and not the other and is there a way I could add/subtract in the timestamp in the URL